# Android: Insert text into EditText at current position

Tags: android, insert, android-edittext

I want to insert a constant string into an EditText by the press of a button. The string should be inserted at the current position in the EditText.
If I use `EditText.append` the text gets inserted at the end of the EditText.

How can I do that? I couldn't find a suitable method.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try using `EditText.getSelectionStart()` to get the current position of the cursor. Then you can use String.subString to get the text before and after the cursor and insert your text in the middle.

Answer (score 105):

Cpt.Ohlund gave me the right hint. I solved it, now, partly with using `EditText.getSelectionStart()`, but I realized that you can also replace the selected text with the same expression and you don't need `String.subString()` for that.

```
int start = Math.max(myEditText.getSelectionStart(), 0);
int end = Math.max(myEditText.getSelectionEnd(), 0);
myEditText.getText().replace(Math.min(start, end), Math.max(start, end),
        textToInsert, 0, textToInsert.length());
```

This works for both, inserting a text at the current position and replacing whatever text is selected by the user. The `Math.max()` is necessary in the first and second line because, if there is no selection or cursor in the EditText, `getSelectionStart()` and `getSelectionEnd()` will both return -1. The `Math.min()` and `Math.max()` in the third line is necessary because the user could have selected the text backwards and thus start would have a higher value than end which is not allowed for `Editable.replace()`.

Comment: The docs specifically say you should not modify the contents of the object returned by EditText.getText() https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#getText()

Answer (score 99):

This seems simpler:

```
yourEditText.getText().insert(yourEditText.getSelectionStart(), "fizzbuzz");
```

However, Manuel's answer might be better if you want to replace any selected text with the inserted text.

Comment: This is without a doubt the best answer. It should be accepted. There's no reason I've seen to reinvent the wheel and it maintains the `Editable` without overwriting it with a `setText()` call which is crucial in most applications. Cleanest, simplest, and least obstructive to other elements in the `EditText`

Comment: is this faster than using substring?

Comment: If there is a range of text already selected, then just inserting at the beginning of the selection is probably not what the user expects.

Comment: The docs specifically say you should not modify the contents of the object returned by EditText.getText() https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#getText()

Answer (score 6):

**For Kotlin** simply do that:

```
editText.text.insert(editText.selectionStart, "Your Text Here")
```

Answer (score 5):

I think this function will help for you :

```
public void insertConstantStr(String insertStr) {
    String oriContent = editText.getText().toString();
    int index = editText.getSelectionStart() >= 0 ? editText.getSelectionStart() : 0;
    StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder(oriContent);
    sBuilder.insert(index, insertStr);
    editText.setText(sBuilder.toString());
    editText.setSelection(index + insertStr.length());
}
```

Comment: Amazing, tried all other solutions where none works for Xamarin Android. In Java, the Replace function has more parameters than the one in Xamarin. This is just perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Editable editable = new SpannableStringBuilder("Pass a string here");

yourEditText.text = editable;