# Xamarin android insert at current position in EditText

Tags: android, xamarin, android-edittext

I have an **edittext** view that I need to be able to insert some special words at the current position of the cursor.  I know how to find it using **editview.SelectionStart**. I am having a problem in actually inserting the new word at that position.

I want to be able to insert the new word at that position.

I have tried this [Android: Insert text into EditText at current position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609174/android-insert-text-into-edittext-at-current-position) and under xamarin the insert format does not seem to exist.

I have also tried this code:

```
string word =  "ReservedWord";

var insertPoint = currentField.SelectionStart;

editSubject.Text.Insert (insertPoint, word);
```

Like shown in [Insert character between the cursor position in edit text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7661104/insert-character-between-the-cursor-position-in-edit-text)

How can I do this?

Mahalo

Don French

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vipul Mittal was on the correct track. The code he presented causes a runtime error in the last substring was out of bounds. The correct code is

```
string text=editSubject.Text;
int startPoint = editSubject.SelectionStart;
int endPoint = editSubject.SelectionEnd;
editSubject.Text = text.Substring(0, startPoint) + word + text.Substring (endPoint,(text.Length - endPoint ));
```

Since both start and end are the same in my current case, using the same value for startPoint and endPoint works fine. However by using the above code, I also support replacing the selected text with the special word.

Note this assumes the startPoint is less than the end point. This may not always be the case is my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Try following code:

```
string text=editSubject.Text;

editSubject.Text = text.Substring(0, insertPoint)+word+text.Substring(insertPoint, text.Length);
```

Comment: Does that mean the entire text of the editText gets copied back and forth?  I saw that solution however not enthused about the copy of the text.