# What is the best way to put an edit text in the middle of a text string?

Tags: android, android-edittext, word-wrap

I would like to create a fill in the blank activity.
Example: 
"The weather was (EDIT TEXT HERE) yesterday."
"The boys played(EDIT TEXT HERE) at recess."
"Lucy drank (EDIT TEXT HERE) at lunch yesterday."

The way I have it set up now, I have a text view before and after the edit text.  The problem is the text of the text views are being set by putStringExtra method sent from an intent.  I never know how long the text of either view will be.  If the text is too long, then the second view's text gets bunched up at the end.  That is, the text wraps on the second text view.  What I'd like to achieve is the text to wrap around the whole screen. Currently, I'm checking the amount of lines of the second text view.  If there's more than one, then I'm placing that text in a textview in a layout below the first layout.  It seems like there's an easier way to do this.  Here's my code, thanks for your help:

```
 public void setText(double w, double t) {
    final double HalfScreenWidth = w;
    final double totalScreenWidth = t;
    TextView1.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("SentPart1"));
    TextView2.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("SentPart2"));
    TextView3.setText("");


    TextView1.measure(MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    tVWidth = TextView1.getMeasuredWidth();

    if (totalScreenWidth > 1100) {
        linLay1.removeAllViews();
        linLay2.removeAllViews();

        linLay1.addView(TextView1);
        linLay1.addView(EditText);
        linLay1.addView(TextView2);
        linLay1.addView(TextView3);
    } else if (tVWidth > HalfscreenWidth && totalScreenWidth < 1100) {
        linLay1.removeAllViews();
        linLay2.removeAllViews();

        linLay1.addView(TextView1);
        linLay1.addView(EditText);
        linLay2.addView(TextView2);
    } else if (tVWidth < HalfScreenWidth && totalScreenWidth < 1100) {
        linLay1.removeAllViews();
        linLay2.removeAllViews();
        linLay1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        linLay2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        linLay1.addView(TextView1);
        linLay1.addView(EditText);
        linLay1.addView(TextView2);
        linLay2.addView(TextView3);
        h.postDelayed(r, 100);

    }

}

final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        int lineCount = TextView2.getLineCount();
        if (lineCount == 1) {
            linLay2.removeView(TextView3);
            linLay1.addView(TextView3);
        } else if (lineCount == 2) {
            int lineStart0 = TextView2.getLayout().getLineStart(0);
            int lineEnd0 = TextView2.getLayout().getLineEnd(0);
            int lineStart = TextView2.getLayout().getLineStart(1);
            int lineEnd = TextView2.getLayout().getLineEnd(1);

            CharSequence extraText0 = TextView2.getText().subSequence(
                    lineStart0, lineEnd0);
            CharSequence extraText =  TextView2.getText().subSequence(lineStart,
                    lineEnd);
            TextView2.setText(extraText0);
            TextView3.setText(extraText);

        } else if (lineCount == 3) {
            int lineStart0 = TextView2.getLayout().getLineStart(0);
            int lineEnd0 = TextView2.getLayout().getLineEnd(0);
            int lineStart1 = TextView2.getLayout().getLineStart(1);
            int lineEnd1 = TextView2.getLayout().getLineEnd(1);
            int lineStart2 = TextView2.getLayout().getLineStart(2);
            int lineEnd2 = TextView2.getLayout().getLineEnd(2);

            CharSequence extraText0 = TextView2.getText().subSequence(
                    lineStart0, lineEnd0);
            CharSequence extraText1 = TextView2.getText().subSequence(
                    lineStart1, lineEnd1);
            CharSequence extraText2 = TextView2.getText().subSequence(
                    lineStart2, lineEnd2);

            CharSequence oneTwo = TextUtils.concat(extraText1, extraText2);
            TextView2.setText(extraText0);
            TextView3.setText(oneTwo);

        } else if (lineCount == 4) {
            int lineStart0 = TextView2.getLayout().getLineStart(0);
            int lineEnd0 = TextView2.getLayout().getLineEnd(0);
            int lineStart1 = TextView2.getLayout().getLineStart(1);
            int lineEnd1 = TextView2.getLayout().getLineEnd(1);
            int lineStart2 = TextView2.getLayout().getLineStart(2);
            int lineEnd2 = TextView2.getLayout().getLineEnd(2);
            int lineStart3 = TextView2.getLayout().getLineStart(3);
            int lineEnd3 = TextView2.getLayout().getLineEnd(3);

            CharSequence extraText0 = TextView2.getText().subSequence(
                    lineStart0, lineEnd0);
            CharSequence extraText1 = TextView2.getText().subSequence(
                    lineStart1, lineEnd1);
            CharSequence extraText2 = TextView2.getText().subSequence(
                    lineStart2, lineEnd2);
            CharSequence extraText3 = TextView2.getText().subSequence(
                    lineStart3, lineEnd3);

            CharSequence oneTwo = TextUtils.concat(extraText1, extraText2,
                    extraText3);
            TextView2.setText(extraText0);
            TextView3.setText(oneTwo);
 }
linLay1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        linLay2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

I put in a runnable because it seems like Android needs a little pause in order to draw the text on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `LinearLayout` in horizontal orientation and put `TextView` on both sides of your `EditText`. Something like this :

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="The weather was " /> <!-- Just for short answer, should be put elsewhere -->
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/myEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" yesterday." /> <!-- Just for short answer, should be put elsewhere -->
</LinearLayout>
```

---

After that in your code, you can set the text like this :

```
// Written here as if it where put in and Activity
public void setYesterdayWeather(final String text) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            TextView v = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
            v.setText(text);
        }
    });
}
```

---

After that, you can listen to changes using a `TextWatcher` and resize the `EditText` so that it always wraps its text like this :

```
// On inflation, likely in Activity.onCreate()
final TextView v = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
v.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    [...]

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        float textSize = v.getPaint().measureText(s, start, start + count);
        // onTextChanged may run on Ui Thread, but if it's not the case, the following statement must be called inside a Runnable posted to the main Looper.
        v.setWidth(textSize); // Eventually, take some extra space for padding ?
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you but the second text view wraps around itself...it bunches up after the edit text.  I would like the text to wrap around the entire screen.

Comment: What you need is resize the `EditText` each time its text change. Register using a `TextWatcher`. Then, you can obtain the new size of the text using `TextView.getPaint().measureText`.

Comment: Thank you but the TextViews sizes are changing.  Also, in your javascript, you're casting the edit text as a textview then setting the text?  I want the user to type text into the text view.  But I like the idea of a textwatcher.  I'll look into that.  Thanks.

Comment: Of course, if the `EditText` becomes too large, the whole text (that is "Wheather was <weather> yesterday") won't fit on a single line, but that's another problem. Maybe some misunderstanding, but my code is regulard java, not javascript. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: What about edittext.append()?  Or possibly this answer:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609174/android-insert-text-into-edittext-at-current-position

Comment: In fact, if you use an `EditText` i assume that the user modifies the text, so you don't want to use a sole `EditText` because the user will then be able to modify also the 'static' text (that is, for example "Wheather was "), right ?

Comment: If your text doesn't fit on a single line i suggest you change your design, either :

Comment: - Putting words altogether differently so that the editable text can be placed at end, like a result (f.e. : "Weather yesterday was : " -> And the weather goes a line under)

Comment: - Putting the single-line `EditText` on a line of its own, surrounded by two multiple lines `TextView` above and under.

Answer (score 0):

you can set it in the activity :

```
String chaine ="The weather was"+getIntent().getExtras().getString("your String name")+"yesterday." ;
        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setText(chaine);
```

In the XML :

Comment: if you want that you use EditText change the textView with EditText