# Freely position cursor in EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Android's EditText has many features. But (please correct me, if I'm wrong) not the one I am searching for. I am trying to get a similar behaviour like the S Memo app on Samsung devices (other notes apps may have this feature as well), where you have the EditText with the note content and you can click on any position where the cursor should jump to. Normal EditText's would just place the cursor at the end of the text which may not get far enough to the position where you clicked.

I thought about filling my empty space with spaces, but I don't know how I could get the number of spaces that fit in the line

Another big problem is that when if position a portion of text somewhere in my note and I use spaces to fill the empty room, with every new letter I type, I move everything that's behind it.

I have no idea what I should do. And even did not find a library that would help me.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609174/android-insert-text-into-edittext-at-current-position

Comment: This doesn't help me. I don't want to insert text programmatically. I just want the user to position the cursor at **any** position on the screen and type there.

Comment: Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I need it, too.